# get url parameter after # sign drupal

Tags: url, drupal-7

every body
if we want to get parameters in url like that

```
/node/x/y
we use arg(1) -> get x and arg(2) -> get y
but if i have a url like that 
/node/x/y#abc
```

how can I get `abc` parameter in drupal thank so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From server side, you cannot get the part of the URL after the `#` sign or the `#` sign itself.

Browser do not send anything after the `#` sign to the server that cause a page load. That's why you see `#` in URLs with many Ajax applications (HTML5 can change the full URL though).

If you still need to show different content based on the hash tags, you will have to add some Ajax to make a second request to the server via JavaScript.

Comment: ok, thank you so much, in my opinion, I will get all url by this function <?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?> and what we need to do now is some string manipulation